# How can I stop creeper griefing without changing the gamerule?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I play on a server without mods and I want to use villagers to automatically farm crops. We play with mobgriefing off so the farm won't work.

How can I allow mob griefing for the villagers but not for creepers?

Comment: mobGrifing false just keeps monsters from breaking blocks. How could this possibly stop a mobfarm from working? Is there a new farm concept that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @Fungo not too sure, but it may be that without mobGriefing, farmer villagers cannot farm. Letting Farmers farm is one way to make villagers breed infinitely in 1.8 (afaik because they will throw bread at each other once their inventory is full).

Comment: @Fungo Villagers cannot farm/replant for automatic wheat farms. Withers cannot destroy blocks for automatic wood/cobble farms.

Comment: Thanks. I thought they meant "farming villagers" not "making villagers farm for you"

Comment: I think he means that the villagers are not harvesting crops when mob griefing is turned off. This makes sense if the game views villager farmers as a type of griefing, so the OP is asking if it is possible to turn off mob griefing for creepers, but on for villagers.

Comment: I like how "Villager farming" = "mob griefing"...

Answer (score 13):

Here is what worked with some tests on a vanilla server and in single player.  Place this in a command block and run it on a clock. This creeper does not do player or block damage.

```
/entitydata @e[type=Creeper] {ExplosionRadius:0}
```

Comment: Great first answer! Welcome to the site. Apologies for late answers are not needed here, unlike a forum, this site's questions are meant to be always valid. Check out the [tour]!

Answer (score 1):

Creepers will stay away from ocelots. So station ocelots (on leash) around your area

Answer (score -5):

The only vanilla way I can think of would be using peaceful mode, and there might be some mods that do that, but do you really want to go either of those routes?

My best idea is to stop running into creepers. Light up the area you don't want to be griefed and you will be mostly okay.

In addition, if you are interested, lighting the area will give you a great opportunity to build a mobfarm.